# jquery hash link to new page scrolling to different anchors

Tags: jquery, anchor, scrolltop, anchor-scroll

I am using some jQuery to do the following:

From page 1, link to anchor on page 2 - but load the page first, then scroll to the anchor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('.Anchor').offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

My link is like this domain.com/page2.html#anchor-name

The anchors are like this:

```
<div name="anchor-name" class="Anchor">&nbsp;</div>
```

The above works fine for just 1 anchor.

Ho do I edit the above jQuery, so that I can have multiple anchors on page 2 & links to them.

i.e.

```
<div name="anchor-name" class="Anchor">&nbsp;</div>
<div name="anchor-fred" class="Anchor">&nbsp;</div>
<div name="anchor-bert" class="Anchor">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work?

Link to it as domain.com/page2.html#fred

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash + "-anchor").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
    });
</script>

<div id="name-anchor">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="fred-anchor">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="bert-anchor">&nbsp;</div>
```